# UISearchBar func with Firebase Database and swift

Tags: swift, database, firebase, uisearchbar

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableViewhospitalss: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


//list to store all the Hospitals
var hospitalsList = [hospitalsModel]()
var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered:[String] = []
```

and the funcs

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = hospitalsList.filter  ({ (text) -> Bool in
        let temp: NSString = text! as NSString
        let range = temp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableViewhospitalss.reloadData()
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tltk.png)

any one have any suggestion please it gives me error 
Cannot assign value of type '[hospitalsModel]' to type '[String]'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to filter and convert 'hospitalsModel' to String because your var filtered is [String], try to use map or filter -> return the same type.

Comment: I don't understand what I should do can you tell me

Comment: change the type of filtered, var filtered: [hostpitalsModel]

Comment: can I send you the file as zip and you edit it for me ? please if you can sir

Comment: Sure send me to fenk86@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

class hospitalsModel: NSObject {

```
var id: String?
var name: String?
var subName: String?
var number: String?
var location: String?
var content: String?
var img: String?
var ta5sos: String?
var workTime: String?
var location2 : String?
var aamOrTa5sosy : String?
var latitude: Float?
var longtude: Float?


init(id: String?, name: String?, subName: String?, number :String?, location:String?,content: String?, img: String?, ta5sos: String?, workTime: String?, location2 : String?, aamOrTa5sosy : String?, latitude: Float? , longtude: Float?){
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.subName = subName
    self.number = number
    self.location = location
    self.content = content
    self.img = img
    self.ta5sos = ta5sos
    self.workTime = workTime
    self.location2 = location2
    self.aamOrTa5sosy = aamOrTa5sosy
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longtude = longtude


}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
class HospitalModel: NSObject  {
 var id: String?
 var name: String?
 var subName: String?
 var number: String?
 var location: String?
 var content: String?
 var img: String?
 var ta5sos: String?
 var workTime: String?
 var location2 : String?
 var aamOrTa5sosy : String?
 var latitude: Float?
 var longtude: Float?


 init(id: String?, name: String?, subName: String?, number :String?, location:String?,content: String?, img: String?, ta5sos: String?, workTime: String?, location2 : String?, aamOrTa5sosy : String?, latitude: Float? , longtude: Float?){
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.subName = subName
    self.number = number
    self.location = location
    self.content = content
    self.img = img
    self.ta5sos = ta5sos
    self.workTime = workTime
    self.location2 = location2
    self.aamOrTa5sosy = aamOrTa5sosy
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longtude = longtude
 }

 class func filterByName(collection: [HospitalModel], text: String) -> [HospitalModel] {
    return collection.filter({ text.lowercased().range(of: $0.name ?? "") != nil  })
 }

 class func filterBySubname(collection: [HospitalModel], text: String) -> [HospitalModel] {
    return collection.filter({ text.lowercased().range(of: $0.subName ?? "") != nil  })
 }
}
```